# Button click to show new page

Tags: java, android, mobile

I have a button on an app. Upon clicking this button a new page should appear. The new page will have a list of videos pulled from somewhere online. My problem now: 


1. I have the xml page I want to show, and the java class linked to it. I know how to make a button, set an on click listener and make the onClick() method. What do I put into that onClick() method? 


2. Help me become more articulate in how I describe Android processes, give me material to read, links to Android documentation. Every time I go into read someting I am overwhelmed; so I've decided to break it down into discrete and manageable tasks. What can I read that will help me understand Android terminology and how applications are ment to function better?

Thank you,
Dave

Comment: Answer 1:write android Intent Answer 2 : read androiddeveloper site

Comment: If you don't need to create the button while application is running,you can define your onclick method in the xml file like this."android:onClick="newView"".Then inside the onClick method simply load the new view that you want.Example:setContentView(R.layout.newView);newView is the name of your newly created view.That's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put  in your onClick() method this code:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Don't forget to add your new activity in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="NextActivity"/>
```